# FluentSecurity: How to assign multiple roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluent-security

In ASP.NET MVC, we can assign multiple roles in AuthorizeAttribute. I'm currently using Fluent Security. The documentation says RequireRolePolicy can support one or more roles.

I want to do the code below:

```
 configuration.For<MyController>(x => x.Index()).RequireRole("Administrator, Editor");
```

but it seems that it only checks one role. How to assign multiple roles to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got it now.

```
 configuration.For<MyController>(x => x.Index()).RequireAllRolesPolicy("Administrator", "Editor");
```