# MVCSiteMap Node Requring Multiple Roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, roles, mvcsitemapprovider

I've set up my menu using MVCSiteMap and I have this node:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Courses Form" controller="Booking" action="Course" roles="CORLIC, VIEWCOBO"/>
```

I'm trying to enforce that this node must have roles "CORLIC" AND "VIEWCOBO" for it to be visible but of course this means that it will be displayed if the user has either of the above.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roles attribute is for interoperability with ASP.NET and should not be used in an MVC-only application.

For MVC, if you are already defining the AuthorizeAttribute on your controller actions, MvcSiteMapProvider will automatically pick them up and hide the matching nodes accordingly if [security trimming](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Security-Trimming) is enabled.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Course()
{
    return View();
}

[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Course(CourseModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Implementation omitted
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

The default [AuthorizeAttribute](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) accepts roles, but it works in the same way as the roles attribute - that is, any role that the user is in will cause it to succeed.

However, you could inherit AuthorizeAttribute yourself and override the [IsAuthorized method](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L84) to change the logic as needed.

```
public class SpecialAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private string _requiredRoles;
    private string[] _requiredRolesSplit = new string[0];

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the required roles. The user must be a member of all roles for it to succeed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The roles string.
    /// </value>
    /// <remarks>Multiple role names can be specified using the comma character as a separator.</remarks>
    public string RequiredRoles
    {
        get { return _requiredRoles ?? String.Empty; }
        set
        {
            _requiredRoles = value;
            _requiredRolesSplit = SplitString(value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether access for this particular request is authorized. This method uses the user <see cref="IPrincipal"/>
    /// returned via <see cref="HttpRequestContext.Principal"/>. Authorization is denied if the user is not authenticated,
    /// the user is not in the authorized group of <see cref="Users"/> (if defined), or if the user is not in any of the authorized 
    /// <see cref="Roles"/> (if defined).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionContext">The context.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if access is authorized; otherwise <c>false</c>.</returns>
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("actionContext");
        }

        IPrincipal user = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal;
        if (user == null || user.Identity == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Ensure all of the roles in RequiredRoles are present.
        if (_requiredRolesSplit.Length > 0 && !_requiredRolesSplit.All(user.IsInRole))
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Call the base class to check the users and roles there.
        return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Splits the string on commas and removes any leading/trailing whitespace from each result item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="original">The input string.</param>
    /// <returns>An array of strings parsed from the input <paramref name="original"/> string.</returns>
    internal static string[] SplitString(string original)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(original))
        {
            return new string[0];
        }

        var split = from piece in original.Split(',')
                    let trimmed = piece.Trim()
                    where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed)
                    select trimmed;
        return split.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then you can specify which roles are required by using the new property.

```
[SpecialAuthorize(RequiredRoles = "CORLIC, VIEWCOBO")]
public ActionResult Course()
{
    return View();
}

[SpecialAuthorize(RequiredRoles = "CORLIC, VIEWCOBO")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Course(CourseModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Implementation omitted
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Another possible option is to use [FluentSecurity](https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity) as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046111/fluentsecurity-how-to-assign-multiple-roles). For FluentSecurity v2.0 to work with MvcSiteMapProvider, you need to copy the [HandleSecurityAttribute code](https://github.com/kristofferahl/FluentSecurity/blob/master/FluentSecurity/HandleSecurityAttribute.cs) into your project and change it to inherit from AuthorizeAttribute instead of Attribute, then use it as specified in the FluentSecurity documentation.