# Using mvcSitemap with ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, mvcsitemapprovider, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

How can I integrate mvc sitemap in ASP.NET MVC application to provide Role based Access control, and is it the best why or there is a better way to have role based access ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to implement role based security in asp.net mvc is to use ASP.Net membership provider where u can easily use `[Authorize]` attribute.

You can authorize a single actionresult as :

```
[Authorize]  <--Attribute for role based security
public ActionResult YourAction()
{.....}
```

You can authorize a complete Controller as :

```
[Authorize]
public class YourController : Controller
{.....}
```

To restrict access for specific roles, use:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Client")]
public ActionResult YourAction()
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Kartikeya Khosla's answer (which is correct), you can customize the behavior of AuthorizeAttribute, if needed, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890711/mvcsitemap-node-requring-multiple-roles). Just be sure you are using the [correct NuGet package for MVC 5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5/).